# vim recent changes breaks vmap?

Tags: vim, vimrc

The same procedure works on my VIM 7.4 patch 1-1572 but not on my VIM 7.4 patch 1-1718, is there anything changed in between that affects this?

Procedure:

```
$ vim -u /dev/null some-file
```

Then in vim

```
:set nocompatible
:vmap <C-F6> "+y
```

Then type some text, press `v` to enter visual mode, select the text, then press `Ctrl-F6`. Then in normal mode, press `"+gP`. In earlier version, copy-paste are successful but in newer version nothing happens.  Any thoughts?  Is it my vmap incorrect, if yes, what would it be to achieve the same effect?

Comment: It works correctly for me. 7.4 is up to patchlevel 1795, so it's entirely possible this problem has been fixed in a more recent patch. If possible try updating and test again.

Comment: Otherwise, it's best to send an email to vim_dev mailing list.